# Preparation of data for select from the data model

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a form with 2 selects, one is a list of users, second is a list of cars of this user. I have a problem with listing all cars for a given user from a model with data.
The data in the *FirstClassViewModel* model is filled correctly, here is its structure:

```
public class FirstClassViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<User> Users { get; set; }
    public int FirstSurveyId { get; set; }
    public int SecondSurveyId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string? UserId { get; set; }
    public string? UserName { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Cars { get; set; }
}
```

Select users in *cshtml* file

```
<select 
id="selectUser"
     class="form-control"
     asp-items="@Model.Users.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.UserName, Value = x.UserId })"
     asp-for="@Model.UserId">
        <option selected disabled>Select...</option>
</select>
```

How to get a list of cars assigned to the user in the selection, depending on the user's choice?